# Logging Kafka Streams/Kafka Connect metrics for monitoring purposes

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, metrics, health-monitoring

I'm working on building a real time processing pipeline using Kafka Streams for processing data coming from Kafka and Kafka Connect to integrate the data into MongoDB. The next phase is to log both Kafka Streams and Connect metrics (latency, throughput, skipped records, ... ) and write to Standard Output. What's the efficient way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why standard output? Prometheus w/ JMX exporter is almost the open source industry standard nowadays

Comment: We have already developed a middleware that gets the logs of log4j and monitor it on Kibana. And since log4j uses stdout by default i was wondering we can do the same with Kafka metrics and let the middleware send it to Kibana to be monitored also.

Comment: So you're effectively ignoring Elasticsearch blogs? https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-java-applications-with-metricbeat-and-jolokia + https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-observability-embracing-prometheus-and-openmetrics-standards-for-metrics